# Azure Point-to-Site : RDP

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

I configured a P2S VPN and was able to access the Jump-box in the Hub Virtual Network via a private IP address.

[image]

Using the same P2S VPN, I cannot reach the VM in the Production subscription while I could RDP into the VM from the Jumb-box directly.

[image]

RDP is allowed at the NSG level

[image]

RDP is allowed at the firewall level

[image]

Hub-to-Spoke Peering is done

[image]

Spoke-to-hub Peering is done

[image]

> 10.0.0.68 is the firewall IP

Routing table is configured as shown below

[image]

and

[image]

> I feel that this is more of a Firewall / Route Table issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I tried to reproduce the same issue in my environment and got the below results*

Remote desktop has the feature to connect the other computers to resolve the issue find the below steps

*Change the firewall settings*

Click on Windows button and search "allow-app through windows firewall" and changed the settings as mentioned in the screenshot

[image]

2). Allow the remote desktop connection

Click the windows button and search for "*allow remote desktop connection*"

[image]

3). Adding the RDGCLIENT transport key
Press *windows + R* and type *regedit* and enter

[image]

4). Changing the network properties
press *windows + I* and *network and properties* and change the network status is to *Private*

*Note: If all the settings to be properly connected and if still not able to connect, for particular subscription we may have the restrictions to connect the RDP, Contact the admin department*